# Problema con fetch javascript php mysql

Tags: javascript, fetch

Hola amigos tengo un problema a la hora de hacer una petición con fetch, lo que hago es hacer la peticion aun archivo php el cual se conecta a una base de datos y me trae los datos, el problema pasa en el fetch pues le paso una variable asi fetch('tapa.php?tapa='+e.target.value) esa variable es para adjuntarla a la consulta en el WHERE,  el problma que me da en consola es el siguiente
apps.js:77 Ocurrió un error SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "
"... is not valid JSON  el fetch entro en el catch y me sale ese error, ahora se pensara que esta mal mi archivo json ,PERO lo raro es que si mi fetch lo pongo asi fetch("tapa.php?tapa='IL24'") es decir le paso manualmente el valor de la variable me trae los datos sin problema,
ya comprobe que la variable tenga ese codigo pero no me fnuciona adjunto codigos.

```
familia.addEventListener("change",function(e){
    console.log(e.target.value)
    tablaFam=e.target.value;
    alert(tablaFam)
    fetch('tapa.php?tapa='+e.target.value)
  
      


   
    .then(res => {
        if(!res.ok) {
            throw new Error('Hubo un error en la respuesta');
        }//en if
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(datos => {
      
        let html = '<option value="">Tapa</option>';
        if(datos.data.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < datos.data.length; i++) {
                html += `<option value2="${datos.data[i].nombre_tapa}"  value="${datos.data[i].clave_tapa}">${datos.data[i].clave_tapa}- ${datos.data[i].nombre_tapa}</option>`;
            }//end for
        }//end if
        document.querySelector('#tapa').innerHTML = html;

        /*codigo para armar la descripcion */
        var valorFamilia = $('option:selected', e.target).attr('value2');
        console.log(valorFamilia)
        familiaValor=valorFamilia;
         //fin de codifp para armar desciprcion
       
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Ocurrió un error '+error);
    });
})
```

Comment: Si aparece `Unexpected token '<'`, hacé un `console.log` de la respuesta que estás obteniendo. Probablemente te está devolviendo el error en HTML (por eso empieza en `<`).

Comment: que te regresa `console.log(e.target.value)`  ?